# Web Service Connection Exception on starting ATG Server

Tags: java, jboss, atg

I am getting the following error when I start my ATG - JBOSS server. 
Please help me fix the issue.

```
ERROR [CDLS service] RemoteException testing binding ; nested exception is:
            java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    AxisFault
     faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
     faultSubcode:
     faultString: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
     faultActor:
     faultNode:
     faultDetail:
            {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)**
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor213.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
            at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:153)
            at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:125)
            at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
            at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
            at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
            at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
            at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
            at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
            at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
            at com.philips.cdls.generated.CustomerCareServiceSoapBindingStub.getContactData(CustomerCareServiceSoapBindingStub.java:164)
            at com.philips.cdls.ContactDetailsService.testBinding(ContactDetailsService.java:130)
            at com.philips.cdls.ContactDetailsService.performScheduledTask(ContactDetailsService.java:165)
            at atg.service.scheduler.ScheduledJob.runJobs(ScheduledJob.java:441)
            at atg.service.scheduler.Scheduler$2handler.run(Scheduler.java:760)

            {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:D-12KGKY09300004

    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
            at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
            at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
            at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
            at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
            at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)**
            at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
            at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
            at com.philips.cdls.generated.CustomerCareServiceSoapBindingStub.getContactData(CustomerCareServiceSoapBindingStub.java:164)
            at com.philips.cdls.ContactDetailsService.testBinding(ContactDetailsService.java:130)
            at com.philips.cdls.ContactDetailsService.performScheduledTask(ContactDetailsService.java:165)
            at atg.service.scheduler.ScheduledJob.runJobs(ScheduledJob.java:441)
            at atg.service.scheduler.Scheduler$2handler.run(Scheduler.java:760)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor213.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
            at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:153)
            at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:125)
            at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
            at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
            at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
            ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on "Apache Axis", you're dealing with web services here. The exception tells that connectivity to somewhere timed out, which might mean that

- the endpoint for your web service could not be connected or
- the schema that your web service is referring to couldn't be connected

It might be due to error somewhere in the target address, due to network connectivity issues or due to endpoint not responding for its own reasons.

Beyond that it's anyones guess.